# Ajax control toolkit Collapsable Panel is not expanding

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using Ajax Control toolkit's collapsable panel extender to design a menu.
My requirement is to have a button called "Expand all", on clicking it all the Collapsable panel will open.

How i will do that. somebody please help.

Answer (score 0):

The following javascript would help you:

```
    var ExpandCollapseFlag = true;

    function ExpandCollapsePanel(PanelName) 
    {            
        var collPanel = $find(PanelName);
        if (collPanel == null || collPanel == undefined) return;
        collPanel.set_Collapsed(ExpandCollapseFlag);
    }
    function ExpandCollapsePanels()
    {
        ExpandCollapsePanel("<%=CollapsiblePanelExtender1.ClientID%>");
        ExpandCollapsePanel("<%=CollapsiblePanelExtender2.ClientID%>");
        ExpandCollapsePanel("<%=CollapsiblePanelExtender3.ClientID%>");
        ExpandCollapsePanel("<%=CollapsiblePanelExtender4.ClientID%>");
        ExpandCollapseFlag = !ExpandCollapseFlag;
    }
```